# PHP show only a piece of data from data row

Tags: php, css, mysqli, extract

What I have done so far is to write a function which I call on another page:

`<div style="<?php echo groupColor($_SESSION['username']); ?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></div>`

What it does it that retrieves the `username_css` style from the `xf_user_group` and that way I can color the user's username by the color they have on a xenforo forum board (all username_css contain `color: #somecolorcode;`)

```
function groupColor($username) {

    global $xenforo;

    $xf_getuser = $xenforo->query("SELECT * FROM xf_user WHERE username = '".$username."'");

    if($xf_getuser->num_rows >= 1) {

        $fetch_xf_getuser = $xf_getuser->fetch_array();
        $fetch_xf_getuser_group = $fetch_xf_getuser["display_style_group_id"];

        $xf_getgroupstyle = $xenforo->query("SELECT * FROM xf_user_group WHERE user_group_id = '".$fetch_xf_getuser_group."'");

        if($xf_getgroupstyle->num_rows >= 1) {

            $fetch_xf_getgroupstyle = $xf_getgroupstyle->fetch_array();
            $result_forum_css = $fetch_xf_getgroupstyle["username_css"];

            return $result_forum_css;

        } else {

            die(mysqli_error($xenforo));

        }

    } else {

        die(mysqli_error($xenforo));

    }

}
```

What I am looking to do now, is to only extract `color: #somecolorcode;` from `username_css` so I can use it to color a background instead, like this: `background-color: #somecolorcode;`

Any idea how I should continue? All help is appreciated, and sorry for the bad title, I'm not of sure what the method is called.

EDIT 1:
The `username_css` row does not only contain `color: #colorcode;` but also stuff like: `font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
color: red;`

Comment: you need to include file contains PHP code into the another file in which you are calling the function.

Comment: @sandeepsure Yes I am aware of that. The function works great but not how I want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting all data after color: using strpos and substr:

```
$css = "color:#000000;";
$color = substr($css, strpos($css, ':')+1, 7);

// Color is #000000
echo $color;
```

Comment: The username_css does not only contain color: #somecolorcode; but also other stuff like font-weight: bold; etc etc.

Comment: @P.Nick Is that fixed that always fourth style will be colour in this string?

Comment: @sandeepsure The color style seem to always be the last style tag.

Comment: @P.Nick I Edit the answer, Hope this helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of below line.

```
 return $result_forum_css;
```

replace it with this.

```
 $total_prop = count($result_forum_css);
 $explode_result = explode(";",$result_forum_css);
 return $explode_result[$total_prop-2];
```

Here, based on your comment we will count the total result and the last result will always be blank so, we fetch second last element and so that we negate total count with 2.

Comment: This does not return anything.

Comment: @P.Nick First `echo $result_forum_css;` and let me know that what it will output?

Comment: As said, $result_forum_css; will output the entire data in username_css. For example: font-weight bold; color: red;

Comment: @P.Nick Can you  `echo $result_forum_css` and print the result `$explode_result` from my above code.